# Command executes but code doesn't return error for non existing commands

Tags: go, error-handling

Code in function to run a fzf against an input, while debugging i discovered my code doesn't return errors, this code runs successfully:

```
    reader := strings.NewReader(listOutput.String())

    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w

    cmd := exec.Command("fzf", "--multi")
    cmd.Stdin = reader
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Couldn't call fzf: %v", err)
    }

    w.Close()
```

So i changed the command to something that doesn't exist, but the code still doesn't return "couldn't call command: command not found", just exits.

```
    reader := strings.NewReader(listOutput.String())

    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w

    cmd := exec.Command("idontexist")
    cmd.Stdin = reader
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Couldn't call command: %v", err)
    }

    w.Close()
```

I don't have an idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`cmd.Run()` does return an error, and your `if` block gets properly executed, but since you change the standard output `os.Stdout = w` you just don't see the result on your console / terminal.

The [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) package writes to the standard output.

If you use the [`log`](https://pkg.go.dev/log) package, you will see the error as the `log` package writes to the standard error (which you didn't change):

```
log.Printf("Couldn't call command: %v", err)
```

This will output something like (note the default log format includes the timestamp too):

```
2022/12/07 13:46:19 Couldn't call command: exec: "idontexist": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Or don't change the standard output.

Also do note that [`log.Println()`](https://pkg.go.dev/log#Println) and [`fmt.Println()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Println) do not require a format string. Do use [`log.Printf()`](https://pkg.go.dev/log#Printf) and [`fmt.Printf()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Printf) when you specify a format string and arguments.